# Does Async.Parallel cancel all jobs if there's an exception in one of them?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

I was interested in finding the F# equivalent of `Task.WhenAny` (that deals with `Async<'T>` instead of `Task<'T>`), and the closest thing I found was `Async.Choice`, however, this implementation requires jobs to return `Option<'T>` instead of just `'T` so I wrote my own `Async.WhenAny` (tweaking it from some snippets I found on the internet):

```
type internal ResultWrapper<'T>(value : 'T) =
    inherit Exception()

    member self.Value = value

module AsyncExtensions =

    let private RaiseResult (e: ResultWrapper<'T>) =
        Async.FromContinuations(fun (_, econt, _) -> econt e)

    // like Async.Choice, but with no need for Option<T> types
    let WhenAny<'T>(jobs: seq<Async<'T>>): Async<'T> =
        let wrap job =
            async {
                let! res = job
                return! RaiseResult <| ResultWrapper res
            }

        async {
            try
                do!
                    jobs
                    |> Seq.map wrap
                    |> Async.Parallel
                    |> Async.Ignore

                // unreachable
                return failwith "No successful result?"
            with
            | :? ResultWrapper<'T> as ex ->
                return ex.Value
        }
```

This is a very simple implementation that doesn't deal with cancellation at all, as you can see (at least compared to [Async.Choice](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/807)).

However, I've found that it still cancels the slower jobs somehow, and I don't understand why. Is it because of how `Async.Parallel` works under the hood?

NOTE: to find out if slower jobs are cancelled or not by AsyncChoice or AsyncWhenAny, I wrote this unit test:

```
[<Test>]
member __.``AsyncExtensions-WhenAny job cancellation``() =
    let shortJobRes = 1
    let shortTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds 2.
    let shortJob = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (int shortTime.TotalMilliseconds)
        return shortJobRes
    }

    let longJobRes = 2
    let mutable longJobFinished = false
    let longTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds 3.
    let longJob = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (int longTime.TotalMilliseconds)
        longJobFinished <- true
        return longJobRes
    }

    let result =
        AsyncExtensions.WhenAny [longJob; shortJob]
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo shortJobRes)
    Assert.That(longJobFinished, Is.EqualTo false, "#before")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds 7.0)
    Assert.That(longJobFinished, Is.EqualTo false, "#after")
```

And this with Async.Parallel:

```
[<Test>]
member __.``AsyncParallel cancels all jobs if there's an exception in one?``() =
    let shortJobRes = 1
    let shortTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds 2.
    let shortJob = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (int shortTime.TotalMilliseconds)
        return failwith "foo"
    }

    let longJobRes = 2
    let mutable longJobFinished = false
    let longTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds 3.
    let longJob = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (int longTime.TotalMilliseconds)
        longJobFinished <- true
        return longJobRes
    }

    let result =
        try
            Async.Parallel [longJob; shortJob]
            |> Async.RunSynchronously |> Some
        with
        | _ -> None

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo None)
    Assert.That(longJobFinished, Is.EqualTo false, "#before")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds 7.0)
    Assert.That(longJobFinished, Is.EqualTo false, "#after")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's [look at the source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/24c798bfcee5d6f91ae2c19888baeb9946744c3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L1199) for `Async.Parallel`. Actually reading it and understanding it might take some familiarity with how F# Async works under the hood, but thankfully there's a handy comment on line 1220:

```
// Attempt to cancel the individual operations if an exception happens on any of the other threads
```

And the following code isn't *too* hard to read: it then creates a cancellation token and passes that same token to all the async operations that it kicks off in parallel. If any of them throw an exception, that token is canceled, which means that all the parallel operations are canceled. So the comment accurately reflects the rest of the code, and this answer is basically a longwinded way of saying "Yes" to the question you asked in your question's title. :-)